# Celery beat (Redbeat) on heroku : logs not showing

Tags: heroku, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have a Django app with a periodic task running on Celery.

**Procfile**

```
worker: celery -A myproject worker --loglevel=INFO
beat : celery -A myproject beat --scheduler redbeat.RedBeatScheduler
```

I've tried with both RedBeatScheduler and django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler, same result.

**settings.py**

```
...
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL") or 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_BACKEND_URL = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL") or 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL") or 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_REDBEAT_REDIS_URL = os.environ.get("REDIS_URL") or "redis://localhost:6379/1"
```

**celery.py**

```
...
app = Celery("myproject")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'chord_scraping_00': {
    'task': 'myapp.tasks.chord_scraping',
    'schedule': crontab(minute="0-8"),
    'args': ("00",),
    }
}
```

Locally, it all works just fine.
But when I deploy it to Heroku, I don't see any logs using `heroku logs --tail`

I do get this log repeatedly :
`app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-rugged-87179 sample#active-connections=6 sample#load-avg-1m=0.335 sample#load-avg-5m=0.23 sample#load-avg-15m=0.23 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.15417 sample#memory-total=15629036kB sample#memory-free=6105444kB sample#memory-cached=4767492kB sample#memory-redis=434704bytes sample#hit-rate=0.39511 sample#evicted-keys=0`

But there is no log **app[beat]** as I would expect. Locally I get in Celery's logs :

`INFO/MainProcess] Received task: myapp.tasks.chord_scraping[932eba58-102d-4db2-a274-722200a76d45]`

Is the periodic task even launching ? Where should the log appear if not in the logs tail?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that your beat wokrs and for test purpose i suggest that you lunch it every 2 or 3 minutes `crontab(minute='*/3')`.

To check the worker logs:

In herokuapp admin checkout you app and then:

1. under More choose : `View logs`

[image]

2. under `All Processes` choose worker
   [image]